# I'm looking for a light wordpress theme with beautiful design and html5 basis (to make the site quick loading)

Tags: wordpress, themes, pagespeed

I'm looking for a light theme with beautiful design and html5 basis (to be a quick site) - Anyone have ideas?
I prefer free (or demo-free to test and buy it later if it's really a fast theme).

I was looking around for the html5 boilerplate template - however, it does not allow me to add plugins (not all) - for example, did not give me a visual editor - no sidebar, etc. Its too simple and i cant do almost anything on it - does not work. Any ideas, suggestions and more?

I am currently using the Divi theme, but it is very heavy, so the sites are slowed by 5-6 seconds minimum while they are loading. And that does not work for me.
Please help .

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know your requirements first and should research on that  google it for you and found this [lists](https://athemes.com/collections/fastest-wordpress-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

Page caching will drastically improve load times, even on shared hosting.

But you *could* try one of Automattic's themes: https://wordpress.org/themes/author/automattic/. They're free and do not suffer from feature creep like premium themes tend to. I've great experiences with (rather heavily) modifying them by means of a child theme.